# Instantiating a controller and associated model without a route?

Tags: ember.js

I'm building an application that allows users to create an account and receive personalized recommendations from the site owner.

I have a `SiteOwnerProfileController` which is used to populate the `SiteOwnerProfile` template with the `SiteOwner` model's data. I of course use a route to wire these all together, and it works grandly.

However, I also need to use the `SiteOwnderProfileController` (backed by the `SiteOwner` model) to populate the `navbar` template. Using the 'needs' property on the `NavbarController` allows me to use helpers like `{{controllers.siteOwnerProfile.fullName}}` in my `navbar` template, but only if the user has visited the `SiteOwnerProfileRoute` which has the model hook used to wire the `SiteOwnerProfileController` up with the `SiteOwner` model.

It seems like the best solution would be to set the model directly on the controller so that when an instance of the controller is created the model is available. I've tried using a render helper in a manner akin to `{{render 'navbar' siteOwnerProfile}}`, but doesn't seem to work.

[I've made a jsbin that illustrates the issue.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wovafajajinu/1/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the application route to retrieve the `SiteOwnerProfile` data and set it as the `SiteOwnerProfileController`'s model. Since the hooks of the application route are always executed prior to those of other routes, we can use it to retrieve and assign models to controllers.

Adding the following makes my example function as intended:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return { fullName : 'siteOwnerName' };
  },

  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('siteOwnerProfile').set('model', model);
  }
});
```

[Here's the jsbin with the solution added.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xayatatoya/2/edit)

As an aside, if you need to serve up multiple models from your application route, you can just return a hash from your model hook and assign each model out in setupController. Example:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return {
      siteOwnerProfileModel: {
        fullName : 'siteOwnerName'
      },
      customerModel: {
        name : 'Billy'
      },
      featuredProductModel: {
        type: 'T-shirt'
      }
    };
  },
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('customer').set('model', model.customerModel);
    this.controllerFor('featuredProduct').set('model', model.featuredProductModel);
    this.controllerFor('siteOwnerProfile').set('model', model.siteOwnerProfileModel);
  }
});
```